# In spark streaming can I create RDD on worker

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I want to know how can I create RDD on worker say containing a Map. This Map/RDD will be small and I want this RDD to completely reside on one machine/executor (I guess repartition(1) can achieve this). Further I want to be able to cache this Map/RDD on local executor and use it in tasks running on this executor for lookup.

How can I do this?

Comment: You won't find any easy/pretty was to do this. That's not where Spark specializes. Doing local lookups and such.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot create RDD in worker node. Only driver can create RDD.

The broadcast variable seems be solution in your situation. It will send data to all workers, however if your map is small, then it wouldn't be an issue.

You cannot control on which partition your RDD will be placed, so you cannot just do repartition(1) - you don't know if this RDD will be placed on the same node ;) Broadcast variable will be on every node, so lookup will be very fast

Comment: Thanks for this info. My map may undergo change once in a while. Is it possible to update this Map/Broadcast variable and re-broadcast that to all executors. I found some info on this at: https://gist.github.com/BenFradet/c47c5c7247c5d5d0f076 , Does it work/valid.

Comment: No, broadcast variable should not be changed. Only possible way to update broadcasted data is not create own implementation of AccumulatorV2, which will hold state of your Map - add operation will just replace state

Comment: It is possible to change your data and rebroadcast it. Link to help you: https://gist.github.com/mcnamaras/040a362ca8100347e1a6

Answer (score 0):

You can create RDD on your **driver program** using `sc.parallelize(data)` . For storing Map, it can be split into 2 parts as key, value and then can be stored in RDD/Dataframe as two separate columns.